# SELECT and use values from a table in php and then insert it into a different column in the same table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, mysqli

Suppose I have 4 columns in a table, I SELECT three columns in my PHP do calculations and conversion and want to update the last column with a new update value.

What is the best way to SELECT and INSERT both the values from the same table? 
 I have tried opening a new query inside a condition in the PHP. Didn't work out... Then I tried putting it in the same query "INSERT INTO hired_jobslocal" and the rest of the code. The whole thing crashed.

```
 date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Kolkata");
date_default_timezone_get();
$date = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', time());


$sql = "SELECT hjl.local_job_id, hjl.job_status, hjl.hire_time_date, hjl.hirer_id, hjl.worker_id 
        FROM hired_jobslocal hjl, WHERE $job_status = 'open' AND $diff > 2332800";

    $result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    //Current date time

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
 // output data of each row
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

     //Getting values from table
    $local_job_id = $row["local_job_id"];
    $job_status = $row["job_status"];
    $hire_time_date = $row["hire_time_date"];

    //Checking the difference for 27 days
    //Getting difference in Unix Format(Decimal Seconds)
    $diffinSeconds = strtotime("$date") - strtotime("$hire_time_date");
    $diff = floor($diffinSeconds);

    //Getting differences in days hours and seconds
    $days    = floor($diffinSeconds / 86400);
    $hours   = floor(($diffinSeconds - ($days * 86400)) / 3600);
    $minutes = floor(($diffinSeconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600))/60);
    $seconds = floor(($diffinSeconds - ($days * 86400) - ($hours * 3600) - ($minutes*60)));


    echo $local_job_id, '-local_job_id<br/>';
    echo $hire_time_date, '- Hirer time date<br/>';
    echo $date, '- Current time <br/>';
    echo $days, '-Difference in days <br/>';
    echo $diff, '-Difference in seconds <br/>';
    echo $job_status, '-job Status<br/><br/><br/>';
```

Comment: by insert - do you mean update the value of fourth column in the same row? If so, you can use single update statement. Nothing else is required.

Comment: yes, but it cannot fit in a single query since it has calculations and conversions I don't know how to insert the new values in the last column. I use PHP to do the calculations.

Comment: Show us what code you have now. Theres 2 ways to do that depending on the complexity of the calculations you are doing. Doing it directly in mysql query or selecting, processing results in php then doing an UPDATE in mysql.

Comment: Suppose, there is date time in a column and the current date (using time function PHP). I have to find the date difference and update a column in the same table whether the time has expired or not.

Comment: [That proved to be effective...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43944435/select-and-use-values-from-a-table-in-php-and-then-insert-it-into-a-different-co#comment74921764_43944435)

Comment: *"What is the best way to SELECT and INSERT both the values from the same table?"* - well, you could run a [multi-query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php) or [`INSERT ... SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html).

Comment: Multi-query will work without closing both the connections the table?

Comment: .......yeppper.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a model of what your code should be like :

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT id,col1,col2,col3 FROM your_table WHERE $job_status = 'open' AND $diff > 2332800";
//execute query
//fetch the result and do you calculation
// set a variable to store your id or an array if nur_rows>1
//if num_rows = 1
$query="UPDATE your_table SET col4 =what_you_want_to_enter WHERE id=$your_id";
//else
foreach($your_array AS $your_id){
$query="UPDATE your_table SET col4 =what_you_want_to_enter WHERE id=$your_id";
}
?>
```